# Хранимая процедура с параметрами и транзакцией внутри работает без отката назад

Tags: sql-server

В моей  таблице есть колонка  с  типом   MONEY . В моей хранимой процедуре есть три параметра:

- первый (@Oper1) определяет размер  суммы    на счете, с которого
  переводятся деньги ,
- второй (@Oper2)  определяет размер  суммы    на счете,  куда
  переводятся деньги,
- третий (@Deposit1)  определяет  Id счета, с которого снимаются
  деньги,
- четвертый   (@Deposit2) определяет Id счета, куда переводятся
  деньги.

Есть две инструкции :одна снимает деньги , а другая  переводит деньги .

По идее , если я в третий параметр (куда переводить деньги  ) ввожу номер несуществующего Id,  то никаких изменений в базе не должно происходить вообще, так ведь?

Но тем не менее , моя хранимая процедура работает так ,как будто никаких  транзакций  в ней нет. Как будто  это просто   хранимая процедура. ~

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyBanc] 

    @Oper1  money, @Oper2  money, @Deposit1 int,  @Deposit2 int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET XACT_ABORT ON
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    --SELECT <@Param1, sysname, @p1>, <@Param2, sysname, @p2>

    BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]

  BEGIN TRY

    --BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]

  UPDATE [dbo].[Account]
   SET 
      [Amount] =@Oper1
 WHERE [Id] = @Deposit1



      UPDATE Account 
      SET Amount =@Oper2
      WHERE [Id] =@Deposit2

      COMMIT TRANSACTION [Tran1]

  END TRY

  BEGIN CATCH

      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Tran1]

  END CATCH
END
```

Я буду премного благодарен, если дадут код простой банковской программы, делающей подобные операции. Кстати, SET XACT_ABORT ON  я и использовал и комментировал, результат был один и тот же.

Comment: _По идее , если я в третий параметр (куда переводить деньги ) ввожу номер несуществующего Id, то никаких изменений в базе не должно происходить вообще, так ведь?_ С чего бы? Тут не выбрасывается никаких исключений. Инструкция `UPDATE Account SET Amount =@Oper2 WHERE [Id] =@Deposit2` отрабатывает корректно, изменяет все строки, соответствующие условию. То что, волею случая таких строк оказывается не 1, не 2, не 100500, а 0, никакой роли ни играет.

Answer (score 0):

Как верно заметил @Yaant никаких предпосылок для пояления здесь иключения нет.
Если инструкция UPDATE "не найдет" строки для обновления, это не значит что она не выполняется.

Вы можете проверять наличие вашего идентификатора в отдельном блоке и выполнять инструкции UPDATE только если таковой нашелся, например так:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP (1) 1 FROM Bills WHERE Num = @Deposit1)
BEGIN
 -- тут UPDATE
END
ELSE
BEGIN
 -- тут можно добавить исключение или запись в лог что не нашелся идентификатор
END
```

Обратите внимание что использована вымышленная таблица и название столбца, т.к. вы не приложили схемы БД.

Comment: Теоретически после выполнения `EXISTS` какая-то другая транзакция может удалить аккаунт и тогда `UPDATE` не обновит ни одной записи. Возможно это не реальный сценарий в конкретной системе. И всё-таки, проще наверное не прибегать к дополнительному запросу, а после `UPDATE` проверить `@@ROWCOUNT` и бросить исключение.